# EditText not change with multi language

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I am trying to create a multilingual application.

I inserted an EditText which however does not change its content after the change of language.

The text is taken from an file string.xml.

To check if the problem was in the file I also inserted a TextView, but this changes.

I am attaching my code

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editTxtName"
    android:layout_width="246dp"
    android:layout_height="47dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="61dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="102dp"
    android:background="@drawable/custom_edit_text"
    android:text="@string/InsertName"
    android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView3"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txtHello"
    tools:text="@string/InsertName" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="219dp"
    android:layout_height="29dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="89dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="103dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="103dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="91dp"
    android:background="@drawable/custom_edit_text"
    android:shadowColor="@android:color/background_dark"
    android:text="@string/InsertName"
    android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/btnChangeLanguage"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editTxtName" />
```

Code MainActivity

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

lateinit var btnLang : Button
var isFirstTimeGetFocused = true

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    loadLocate()
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    btnLang = findViewById(R.id.btnChangeLanguage)

    btnLang.setOnClickListener {

        var context: Context
        showChangeLang()

    }

    editTxtName.setOnClickListener(){
        CleanEditText()
    }
}


fun CleanEditText() {
    if (isFirstTimeGetFocused) {
        editTxtName.setText("");
        isFirstTimeGetFocused = false;
    }
}


fun showChangeLang(){

    val listItemsLang = arrayOf("English","French","Italiano")

    var msgBuilder = AlertDialog.Builder(this@MainActivity)
    msgBuilder.setTitle("Choose Language")
    msgBuilder.setSingleChoiceItems(listItemsLang,-1){
        dialog, which ->
        if(which == 0){
            setLocate("en")
            recreate()
        }else if(which == 1){
            setLocate("fr")
            recreate()
        }else if(which == 2){
            setLocate("it")
            recreate()
        }
        dialog.dismiss()
    }

    var mDialog = msgBuilder.create()
    mDialog.show()


}

private fun setLocate(Lang: String?){
    val langLocale = Locale(Lang)
    Locale.setDefault(langLocale)
    val config = Configuration()
    config.locale = langLocale
    baseContext.resources.updateConfiguration(config, baseContext.resources.displayMetrics)


    val editor = getSharedPreferences("Setting", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit()
    editor.putString("My_Lang",Lang)
    editor.apply()
}

private fun loadLocate(){
    val sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("Setting", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
    val langLocale= sharedPreferences.getString("My_Lang","")
    setLocate(langLocale)
}
```

}

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: It kind of makes sense that it would behave this way. The contents of an EditText are expected to be user-entered, so it is probably not reloading those contents in case the user modified them. You'll probably have to manually modify them.

Comment: or try android:hint="@string/InsertName" instead of android:text="@string/InsertName"

Comment: @damienG android:hint="@string/InsertName" works...thanks